# What is blob in the <video src=blob:url>?

Tags: url, youtube

Can anyone explain what the `blob:` indicates in the URL in this video tag?

```html
<video class="" 
       style="width: 640px; height: 360px; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: none; opacity: 1;" 
       src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/5c42620b-a028-451b-9b64-424996802355">
</video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used)

Answer (score 15):

That is a youtube video with [shaka player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) which plays DASH content without browser plugins using [Media Source Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/).

The blob url is generated by `createObjectURL`. for example:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

var assetURL = 'frag_bunny.mp4';
// Need to be specific for Blink regarding codecs
// ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
  //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // closed
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
} else {
  console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the above code, the `assetURL` is not used at all how is blob URL translated into actual video URL?

Comment: There seems to be a step missing here. `assetURL` is defined once and never used with `mediaSource`. All I can see happening here is a blank video. And what is the definition of `sourceOpen()`?

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to understand the code: YouTube evidently wants to make it as difficult as possible to access videos outside of the browser. Calling URL.createObjectURL on a string argument that happens to be a URL just puts "blob:" before it; I don't think we're supposed to know why they wanted to do that.

Comment: @BradenBest the full example is available on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#Examples

Answer (score 2):

It indicates that the url was created using the `URL.createObjectURL` method. You can try `URL.createObjectURL(new MediaSource());` in the console to demonstrate that it creates a blob url.

It seems the youtube developers have set the `src` attribute of the video to a blob url obtained from `URL.createObjectURL`, and they're likely also using the media source extensions API, which allows them to switch the quality of the video based on your connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

A **blob** is a higher-level object which represents immutable raw binary data.

[See examples in javascript and HTML tags](https://javascript.info/blob)

[Blob intreface W3 definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob)