# How do YouTube/Facebook display videos using blob?

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video, blob

I would like to know the process that these websites use to source a video in blob format from their server?

```
<video height="390" width="693" preload="auto" src="blob:https://www.facebook.com/34799f7c-34d4-48c7-976f-1e2ddba0728a"></video>
```

I'm looking to implement the same method on my site.

I am able to source a video using blob. But the process is slow as I have to first retrieve (download) the video from the server, then create the blob.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "video.mp4"); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() 
{
    var video = document.getElementById("videoId");
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send();
```

If the video is 10 minutes long it takes about 15 seconds after the page has loaded for the video source to update.

However, when you watch a video on YouTube for example, it loads almost instantly. How do they load videos so fast using blob?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389001/what-is-blob-in-the-video-src-bloburl

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted this question, it is not bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube uses [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) extensions to have fine-grained control over video playback. However, that's probably more sophisticated than most users need. The simplest way to play back an .mp4 file is:

```
var video = document.getElementById("videoId");
video.src = "video.mp4";
```

This will download only what the user watches, similar to how YouTube works.