# disable direct access to blobs .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, blob

I have seen people disable access to files using htaccess code like this one
[(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)
I would like to know that is it possible that I can disable direct access to blob url like
 **blob:http://youtube.com/jfhdskjhfkdjshfshof**
I don't even know if blob is a protocol or what

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-blob-url-why-it-is-used-explain

Answer (score 1):

You can only disable access to objects/files, which are on your server (because in your example you point to youtube).

And blob is a html object, not an protocol (in your example, the protocol will be http). For more info look at this question:
[What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-blob-url-why-it-is-used-explain)

Comment: then how youtube does it.