# Node JS using selenium Protocol "blob:" not supported. Expected "http:"

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to automate PDF by its URL and my code is:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    console.log(handles[1]);
    browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        console.log(url);

        var file = fs.createWriteStream(url);
        console.log(file);
        var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
        });
    });
})
```

I am getting error:

> Protocol "blob:" not supported. Expected "http:".

Anyone can help with this issue?

Comment: show the output of  `console.log(url)`

Comment: I am getting URL output correctly. This is my URL output: 'blob:http://localhost:4000/da93c099-a646-42bd-bf55-647ea2b114d4'

Comment: take a look what is `blob` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used