# Converting data:image base64 to blob in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to change the URLs from data:image base64 to blob. This is the original code that produces the base64 urls:

```
<script>

    $(window).load(function(){

    function readURL() {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $newinput =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.portimg ');
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                reset($newinput.next('.delbtn'), true);
                $newinput.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
                $newinput.after('<div class="delbtn delete_upload"  title="Remove"><span class="bbb-icon bbb-i-remove2"></span></div>');


$("form").on('click', '.delbtn', function (e) {
    reset($(this));
    $("form").find('#rright-<?php echo $i;?>').hide();
  });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $(".file").change(readURL);


    function reset(elm, prserveFileName) {
        if (elm && elm.length > 0) {
            var $input = elm;
            $input.prev('.portimg').attr('src', '').hide();

            if (!prserveFileName) {
                $($input).parent().parent().parent().find('input.file ').val("");
                //input.fileUpload and input#uploadre both need to empty values for particular div
            }
            elm.remove();
        }
    }

    });

  </script>
```

What I want is to call Object.createObjectURL(this.files[0]) to get the object URL, and use that as the src of your img; (just don't even bother with the FileReader).

Comment: You already have the Blob though in `this.files[0]` why go through the expense of translating it back from base 64?

Comment: @HereticMonkey But how do I get that instead of base64?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the Blob? I mean all you really have to do is cache `this.files[0]` in a variable somewhere where you can use it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I should've explained myself better. Right now the link looks like this: `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAY0AAAGNCAIAAABixbqGAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlw......` and it's a mile long. I want it to look like this `src="blob:https://mysite.c o m/98cd2703-9e3f-4115-8e20-abdc16fef4ad"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make that clear. What you really want then is to just call `Object.`[`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)`(this.files[0])` to get the object URL, and use that as the `src` of your `img`; just don't even bother with the `FileReader`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok, I edited it. Would you be able to help me? I don't know how many people are going to see this post. It didn't get any questions or solutions this far.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function readURL() {
  var file = this.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var base64string = getBase64(file);
  reader.onload = function () {
    reset($newinput.next('.delbtn'), true);
    $newinput.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
    $newinput.after('<div class="delbtn delete_upload"  title="Remove"><span class="bbb-icon bbb-i-remove2"></span></div>');

    var blob = dataURItoBlob(base64string);
  };
  reader.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  };
}
```

Comment: @ ssten I updated my original post. This is what I actually need. I wasn't sure how to articulate it when I first posted my question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will work and due to the vagaries of Stack Snippets, can't demonstrate its viability here on Stack Overflow, but theoretically, you should be able to use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create the appropriate URL for your image, without going through the whole base 64 rigmarole.

```
var $newinput =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.portimg ');
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    $newinput.attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
    // if the above doesn't work, you could try to create a new Blob
    var fileBlob = new Blob(this.files[0], { type: "image/png" }) 
    // Substitute "image/png" with whatever image type it is
    $newinput.attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob));
```

That should render the appropriate URL for the image's source.

Note that it is best practice to revoke the object URL when you are done with it. I'm not sure that's necessary in this case, since presumably you want to show the image until the page is closed. However, if the user can upload a new image, do something like:

```
if ($newinput.attr('src').indexOf('blob') > -1) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL($newinput.attr('src'));
}
```

Add that before setting the new source and you shouldn't need to worry about memory leaks (from this use of `createObjectURL` anyway...).

For more information on Blob URLs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881444/215552) by a now-anonymous user to [What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30864573/215552)

Comment: Sorry, it's not working... The image doesn't show and there's nothing there when I inspect the elements.

Comment: @Alex333 Sorry, this is what happens when I multitask. The `createObjectURL` is on the `URL` object, not on `Object`.

Comment: Hey, it's half way there! When I inspect the elements the new blob link is there, however the image isn't showing. Something in the code is preventing from the image to show... what that might be? This line? `$newinput.attr('src', e.target.result).show();`?

Comment: You might need to specify the type of image... That should be part of the File Blob you get from `this.files[0]`, but maybe it's not there? I'll amend my answer with something to try.

Comment: It's not doing it. I wonder if the problem is in this line `reader.onload = function (e) {` we don't have the reader anymore since this line is gone `var reader = new FileReader();`

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, remove all that reader stuff. You don't need the reader at all, so you don't need `reader.onload` or `reader.readAsDataURL`

Comment: Not sure, maybe I am not doing it right but removing it didn't help. How much would your remove? I do need all that other stuff under `reader.onload = function (e) {` what would you change `reader.onload = function (e) {` to?

Comment: I'd remove that line and the corresponding `}`.

Comment: That's fine; that hooks up your file input to the function and you want to keep that going.

Comment: Removing `reader.onload = function (e) {` and the corresponding `}` didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I see the blob link in the inspect elements, I know the image is there it's just not showing.

Comment: Do you think it will help if you have a working example? Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/vgwz4q9L right now it shows images via `data:image/png;base64`. Thank you!

Comment: `$newInput` does not refer to an `img`. See https://jsfiddle.net/6kwfbzcx/, where I add a new image, set it to the object URL and it displays fine. Reconsider your method of selecting the element.