# How does this <video> tag prevent its contents from being downloaded?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, drm

Taking [this video](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x60y8sn) as an example, here is the html tag which seems to be the critical piece of content:

```
<video
    id="dmp_Video"
    style="display: block; width: 350px; height: 197.436px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"
    playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" x-webkit-airplay="allow"
    operadetachedviewtitle="All Watched Over by Machines of Loving Grace - Episode 3: The Monkey in the Machine and the Machine in the Monkey — Dailymotion"
    src="blob:https://www.dailymotion.com/30c69843-cd99-4101-a8bb-0a6db568dd00"
    controlslist="nodownload">
</video>
```

It is clearly not intended to be downloadable because there is `controlslist="nodownload"` and I notice that it's quite resilient to casual tampering. I would like to know how this is implemented.

If I delete the surrounding clutter nodes in Firefox, I am able to right-click on the  element but the menu option to download is greyed-out. If I disable Javascript, I am not able to right-click on this element at all.

If I put the `https://www.dailymotion.com/30c69843-cd99-4101-a8bb-0a6db568dd00` blob url into the browser directly, or use `wget`, I get a 404.

How have they achieved this?

(I'm not asking you to hack the page for me, I'm asking what I would have to do to make my own videos similarly protected.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used)

Comment: By the way, it has nothing to do with DRM

Answer (score 0):

edit it and paste in:

```
URL.createObjectURL()
```

right before blob and you should be able to download it