# blob url not playing on revoke. how to prevent to download video

Tags: javascript, blob

We have created blob url in site to play videos.
video is getting played well in site whereas we do not want somebody select blob:https://dummy.com/sdjfkab url and paste that in browser to play video to prevent video download.
it is same required as youtube has implemented.
Can some please help on this problem. if we try to revoke blob url then video does not play in site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used)

Comment: Please, take a look on what is blob: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used

"Blob URLs can only be generated internally by the browser. URL.createObjectURL() will create a special reference to the Blob or File object which later can be released using URL.revokeObjectURL(). These URLs can only be used locally in the single instance of the browser and in the same session (ie. the life of the page/document)."

So, no one can select your blob and use it with those link.

Comment: thanks for Answer. We have created blob url. if user copy the url after inspecting element and then paste same url in in tab. he is able to see video directly and he can save that video. How we can prevent that as it is same requirement as we can see in youtube. blob url works only in youtube but if we copy and paste same url in new tab that video does not play. we I am trying to revoke blob url just after assigning url to video source using ajax still that video does not play in site.

Comment: Could you provide an example of such url, that I will be able to run from my browser and watch the video?
Since I'm not sure that it's possible.