# Is it possible to show blob realtime video from other website on another?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, blob

There is a website where people stream their video online (not twitch).

Here is the code with the link to the streaming source

```
<video src="blob:https://some-site-here.com/18357558-8117-4aa5-a8a9-bba9b1055a87"></video>
```

When I post this code on my HTML page I see only one static pic from the stream and it updates on page refreshing.

Is it possible to run this video realtime? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

> Blob URLs can only be generated internally by the browser. URL.createObjectURL() will create a special reference to the Blob or File object which later can be released using URL.revokeObjectURL(). These URLs can only be used locally in the single instance of the browser and in the same session (ie. the life of the page/document).

Quoted from [What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used)