# javascript return me Blob url

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am injecting javascript in android webview to get the videos url when i open youtube.com then youtube return me two urls one is video url which is opened in browser and second is blob url like :

> blob:https://m.youtube.com/22feb068-4df1-4689-898e-a4e9215fe7a6

i want to get the redirected url from the youtube which is playable on chromecast.
i used same javascript in iOS its working fine and webview return [playable url](https://r2---sn-2uja-aix6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1603465864&ei=KJ6SX6SxJozN0wWg5ruYCQ&ip=182.185.203.23&id=o-AP11yLGfsCv9nkMP4s4YE1MEPWEMtoaqGRApIjEIjl_E&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=w5&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-2uja-aix6%2Csn-4wg7ln76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pcm2cms=yes&pl=17&initcwndbps=308750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=92299841&ratebypass=yes&dur=1356.672&lmt=1601118627850730&mt=1603444122&fvip=2&fexp=23915654&c=MWEB&txp=5530434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAL6ZGvVPzfh-476G-y77b_DSsAFILg2lsOIMP8G0AOb9AiBGQuQZrPa4pd6dtHhk_ji2i_u39kg2ktz1Po48URMVZQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgEcwgN8SuSc8rIcJui4K-AGQ-zkgYb46Jvy1x6oO14A0CIGECmAQW736qjHwnIT3XucGxAREvHek7ehwWXrEKhBj-&cpn=sIFNQl_r_Ew8qUvR&cver=2.20201022.02.01&ptk=youtube_single&oid=Q_y2FhDPlibUDBGkS8NaZg&ptchn=9trsD1jCTXXtN3xIOIU8gg&pltype=content) but in android its return Blob url. is there any way to convert blob url to redirected url.

Comment: did you see this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used)

Comment: is not better to use official youtube api to get needed data ? or one of many libs ?

Comment: i don't was to use official youtube api because i am getting url using javascript injection..yes i read about blob url and i use the method it return me undefined.i use same javascript in iOS it return me playable url but in android it return blob url which is not playing in webview.