# Cropped svg in downloading pdf using html2pdf javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, html2pdf

svg it is rendered perfectly in HTML, but when I download it is not rendering properly. why?

**in html**
[image]

**in PDF**
[image]

**Code**

```
function saveAsPDF() {
            var element = document.getElementById('printableArea');
            var opt = {
                margin: 0.3,
                filename: 'download.pdf',
                image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 1},
                html2canvas: {scale: 4, dpi: 72, letterRendering: true},
                jsPDF: {unit: 'in', format: 'A2'},
                html2canvas: {
                    onclone: (element) => {
                        const svgElements = Array.from(element.querySelectorAll('svg'));
                        svgElements.forEach(s => {
                            const bBox = s.getBBox();
                            s.setAttribute("x", bBox.x);
                            s.setAttribute("y", bBox.y);
                            s.setAttribute("width", bBox.width);
                            s.setAttribute("height", bBox.height);
                        })
                    }
                }
            };
            html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
        }
```

Comment: Does this rendering result appear in every browser? E.g. safari has some [known rendering issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949555/convert-svg-with-image-not-working-in-safari) that could be solved by adding some delay before drawing the svg to canvas.

Comment: how could it be done?

Comment: It really depends on your actual svg/html/css code. So please provide a stripped down code example via SO's snippet feature – if your code is too complex: just share a jsfiddle or codepen link (or similar coding platform links). If your pdf rendering issue is browser specific – please add those insights to your question/description (e.g. wether everything is fine in firefox, but screwed up in chromium based browsers).