# how to download "blob:https//someUrl/uuid" file in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, blob

I need to download generated.pdf from "blob:" link
All the common methods throws "Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported" error

All the common methods (Https, Request, Fetch) throws "Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported" error
I is possible at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a blob URL and why it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used)

Comment: You can't do that because it's an internal browser url, can't be accessed from nodejs