# How to load a blob URL that's not marked as insecure?

Tags: javascript, browser, blob, createobjecturl, security-warning

If you go to the "creating a blob" example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#creating_a_blob, you end up getting an URL that starts with "blob:https://", but the browser marks the site as insecure:
[image]

What is required for that to be marked as secure?

To give context of what I'm doing: I have an angular app that can open PDF's from base64 data in new tabs, and this can be any number of PDF's at the same time.

Comment: I guess you should load a proper site and not a blob URI - it could be any blob, created by anyone. What do you want to use this for?

Comment: @Bergi load base64 data that represents PDF's.

Comment: That's weird. Does the PDF contain any forms? I thought browsers display this warning only on interactive pages.

Comment: No interactive forms.
I confirmed it with Edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viewing the pdf through the blob URL (`blob:https://...`) isn't dangerous (unless of course the pdf has something dangerous inside). You can safely ignore the warning.

That warning message comes from the fact that your current URL is not using HTTPS, but blob urls are pointing to a piece of local data in the browser, you don't need a transfer protocol for that.

Here's a good answer describing blob urls in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881444/12914833

But blob URLs aren't really meant for navigating to. They are meant for the `src` attribute of HTML elements, or for a download link via the `a` tag. Here are the elements that support `src`: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_src.asp

Here's an example of how you would use a blob url:

```js
// This function would retrieve a blob from somewhere
// I'm just fetching an image and converting it for convenience
function getBlob() {
  return fetch(
    'https://wealthofgeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/spongebob-rainbow-meme-imagination.jpg'
  ).then((res) => res.blob());
}

getBlob().then(
  (blob) => (document.querySelector('img').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob))
);
```

```html
<img width=300></img>
```

And here's an example of how to allow downloading the blob.

```
// This function would retrieve a blob from somewhere
// I'm just fetching a pdf and converting it for convenience
function getBlob() {
  return fetch('https://uclit.ca/assets/documents/dummy.pdf').then((res) =>
    res.blob()
  );
}

getBlob().then((blob) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.textContent = 'DOWNLOAD';
  a.download = 'dummy.pdf';
  document.body.append(a);
});
```

This won't work in a sandboxed iframe like a snippet, so here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-t5dqpa?file=index.ts,index.html

---

For viewing pdfs without that warning you can either:

1. Embed it into an html page
2. Host the file on a server
3. Let the user download the file

---